# Word macro error - Runtime Error 4608, Value out of range

Tags: vba, vb.net, ms-word

We have a macro we run to format the page for our publisher.  There are several documents that use this macro.  For smaller documents the macro runs without error, for larger documents we receive the error in the subject line of this thread.

Small document - <= 256KB

Large document - >= 500KB

**For the documents that have the error I can open them in Word and manually make the settings without a problem.**

Here is the second version of the macro

```
Function pagestuffB() As String
'
' Format for Publisher
'
'
Dim rv As String
rv = ""
On Error GoTo ErrorHndlr:
    With Application
        .Options.Pagination = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        With .ActiveDocument.PageSetup
            .PaperSize = wdPaperLetter
'            .PageWidth = InchesToPoints(8.5)
'            .PageHeight = InchesToPoints(11)
            .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
            .MirrorMargins = True 'ERROR HERE
            .TopMargin = InchesToPoints(1.34)
            .HeaderDistance = InchesToPoints(0.98)
            .BottomMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
            .FooterDistance = InchesToPoints(0.8)
            .LeftMargin = InchesToPoints(1.61)
            .RightMargin = InchesToPoints(1.4)
            .Gutter = InchesToPoints(0)
            .SectionStart = wdSectionContinuous
            .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = True
            .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
            .LineNumbering.Active = False

            .FirstPageTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
            .OtherPagesTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
            .VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalTop
            .SuppressEndnotes = False
            .TwoPagesOnOne = False
            .BookFoldPrinting = False
            .BookFoldRevPrinting = False
            .BookFoldPrintingSheets = 1
            .GutterPos = wdGutterPosLeft
        End With
    End With
    pagestuffB = rv
Exit Function

ErrorHndlr:
    If rv = "" Then
        rv = "Macro error " & Err.Number
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case Else
        End Select
    End If

    Resume Next
End Function
```

Version info:  Word 2010, VS 2012.

I have the document that failed and will provide it if needed.

**EDIT**:  The documents are [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=95E9849B11BDE22F!1267&authkey=!AGbp4ayAv3vveIo&ithint=folder%2Cdocx)

This is the latest version of the macro, which actually runs, but.... It took .5 hours to format the two documents, two of the smallest, in the link above.

```
Function pagestuffB() As String
'
' Format for Publisher
'
'
Dim rv As String
rv = ""
On Error GoTo ErrorHndlr:
    With Application
        .Options.Pagination = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .WindowState = wdWindowStateMinimize
    End With
    Dim oSec As Section
    For Each oSec In Selection.Sections
        With oSec.PageSetup
            .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait 'moved per macropod
            .PaperSize = wdPaperLetter
            .MirrorMargins = True
            .TopMargin = InchesToPoints(1.34)
            .HeaderDistance = InchesToPoints(0.98)
            .BottomMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
            .FooterDistance = InchesToPoints(0.8)
            .LeftMargin = InchesToPoints(1.61)
            .RightMargin = InchesToPoints(1.4)
            .Gutter = InchesToPoints(0)
            .SectionStart = wdSectionContinuous
            .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = True
            .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True

            .LineNumbering.Active = False
            .FirstPageTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
            .OtherPagesTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
            .VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalTop
            .SuppressEndnotes = False
            .TwoPagesOnOne = False
            .BookFoldPrinting = False
            .BookFoldRevPrinting = False
            .BookFoldPrintingSheets = 1
            .GutterPos = wdGutterPosLeft
        End With
    Next oSec

    pagestuffB = rv
Exit Function

ErrorHndlr:
    If rv = "" Then
        rv = "Macro error " & Err.Number
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case Else
        End Select
    End If

    Resume Next
End Function
```

Comment: Just a guess - try doing this in a Sub instead of a Function.

Comment: It was originally, without any of the On error stuff.  That was added to help track down the error.  The Function so I could use Interop and execute it from a VS app.

Comment: Do the documents that fail have multiple sections?

Comment: @Comintern - all of the documents have multiple sections.  The larger ones have more than the smaller ones.  Did this get down voted?

Comment: If you post the doc, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Tomorrow I can post it, it is at work, and I am not.I submitted it earlier to MS Connect but they haven't posted it yet.  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2499547/word-macro-error-runtime-error-4608-value-out-of-range

Comment: @dbasnett - I'd try setting the page setup per section to see if that works. I've run into similar issues with multi-section Word documents throwing inexplicable errors trying to set parameters across multiple sections at the same time.

Comment: @Comintern - I'll give it a go tomorrow.  Thx for the suggestion.  In another forum someone suggested changing the order.  Two days spent on setting a bunch of properties, what is one more.

Comment: I'm missing the information about which line of code is triggering the error. Without that, no one can help you.

Comment: @CindyMeister - it is in one of the comments.

Comment: @Floam - see edits above.  The files are available.

Comment: @dbasnett, haven't forgotten about you. Will take a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

So I removed these three lines of code and the macro worked very quickly on my computer for those two documents. It seems like you used a recorded macro to build this code. It's certainly hard to grasp what exactly you want this code to do since there are no comments describing what your code does :). Comment underneath if this suggestion does not fix your problem.

```
.BookFoldPrinting = False
.BookFoldRevPrinting = False
.BookFoldPrintingSheets = 1
```

Comment: I'll give it a try.  I am not a VBA person.  All I was trying to do was to set the margins, and yes I recorded what worked.  Thanks.

Comment: @dbasnett did this solve your problem? If so, please mark it as answered to close the question. Thanks!

Comment: @dbasnett are you all set?

Comment: Took an entirely different approach.  Formatted all the pieces to have the same format which meant that the collection didn't have to run the macro.

Comment: @dbasnett, if the problem is solved please mark it as solved.

Comment: P.S. glad you figured it out :)!